# Internet Explorer 8 Image onload with concurrent requests

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, preloader

In my applications, I've inserted a very basic image preloader that basically generates a number of Image objects matching images used in the application and attempts to load them early. This works fine in all browsers - except Internet Explorer 8.

I'm attaching a callback to the onload and onerror events of the Image object, displaying my main page only when all image objects have fired one or the other. However, in Internet Explorer 8, after having created 80 something Image objects each with the same function on onload and onerror, I only get a single callback.

Is this a known issue and is there a workaround?

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: @mamruoc if you and Freed are the same person please log in with that account and add the code. If it's your friend, please ask him/her to add. User can't just add code to other user's post.

Comment: sorry, somehow I managed to change window when trying to update my own question with code example.